# How to get akka's actor name in Java?

Tags: java, akka, actor

i'm new to Akka and Im trying to make a simple project which is aquarium with fishes. The problem is I dont know how to get actor's name which i declared in this line

```
final ActorRef fish1 = system.actorOf(Props.create(Fish.class), "Dora");
```

I tried this:

```
public Fish{
        String actorName = self.path.name;
    }
```

but "self has private access in 'akka.actor.AbstractActor'"

Comment: if Fish does extend `AbstractActor` calling `getSelf().path().name()` should do it. (or just `self().path().name()`)

Comment: You could also simply pass the name as a parameter to the constructor directly, with `Props.create(Fish.class, "Dora")`.

Comment: `self().path().name()` works in 100%, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to use `getSelf()` instead `self`?